# Finding the index of a linear vector field at the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> For the linear vector field $f(x,y) = (f_1, f_2) = (ax+by,cx+dy)$, show that the index with respect to the origin is $\pm 1$ depending on whether $ad-bc > 0$ or $ad-bc < 0$.

I've gone through this calculation four or five times now and I get a different answer every time. Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong! Here's what I've tried:

By definition, the index of a critical point is defined as the index of any Jordan curve that surrounds the point. (I assume the critical point is isolated and unique.) To find the index of a loop $\gamma$, I use
$$Ind(\gamma,f) =  \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_\gamma \frac{f_1 df_2 - f_2 df_1}{f_1^2 + f_2^2} $$
and I choose my Jordan curve $\gamma$ to be the square with corners in $(1,1), (1,-1),(-1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$. Then I can split $\gamma$ into four pieces:
\begin{align*}
& \gamma_1 = \{(x,-1): -1 \leq x \leq 1\} \\
& \gamma_2 = \{(1,y): -1 \leq y \leq 1\} \\
& \gamma_3 = \{(x,1): -1 \leq x \leq 1\} \\
& \gamma_4 = \{(y,-1): -1 \leq x \leq 1\} \end{align*}

The next step is to integrate along each of these line segments:
\begin{align*}
& \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{f_1 df_2 - f_2 df_1}{f_1^2 + f_2^2} = - \arctan \left( \frac{c-d}{a-b} \right) + \arctan \left( \frac{-c-d}{-a-b} \right) \\
& \int_{\gamma_2} \frac{f_1 df_2 - f_2 df_1}{f_1^2 + f_2^2} = \arctan \left( \frac{c+d}{a+b} \right) - \arctan \left( \frac{c-d}{a-b} \right) \\
& \int_{\gamma_3} \frac{f_1 df_2 - f_2 df_1}{f_1^2 + f_2^2} = \arctan \left( \frac{c+d}{a+b} \right) - \arctan \left( \frac{-c+d}{-a+b} \right) \\
& \int_{\gamma_4} \frac{f_1 df_2 - f_2 df_1}{f_1^2 + f_2^2} = \arctan \left( \frac{-c+d}{-a+b} \right) - \arctan \left( \frac{-c-d}{-a-b} \right) \\
\end{align*}
Now, adding these four integrals together I get
$$Index(\gamma,f) = \frac{1}{\pi} \left( \arctan \left( \frac{c+d}{a+b} \right)- \arctan \left( \frac{c-d}{a-b} \right) \right) $$
and finally I use the addition formula for $\arctan$ to get

$$Index(\gamma,f) = \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan \left( \frac{2(ad-bc)}{a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2} \right).$$

Here I can see that the sign of $ad-bc$ determines the sign of the index, but the expression doesn't seem integer-valued at all to me. What's wrong?

**EDIT:** Here's how I solved the integrals along the $\gamma_i$. Use that $df_1 = a\cdot dx = b \cdot dy$ and $df_2 = c \cdot dx = d \cdot dy$. On $\gamma_1$ we have $y = -1$, so we integrate with respect to $x$ and get
\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{f_1 df_2 - f_2 df_1}{f_1^2 + f_2^2} =\int_{\gamma_i} \frac{(ax+by)c\cdot dx-(cx+dy)a\cdot dx}{(ax+by)^2+(cx+dy)^2} = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{(bc-ad)y}{(ax+by)^2+(cx+dy)^2}dx = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\frac{(bc-ad)y}{(ax+by)^2}}{1+(\frac{cx+dy}{ax+by})^2}dx
\end{align*}
But the derivative of the arctangent is
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left( \arctan\left(\frac{cx+dy}{ax+by}\right) \right) = \frac{1}{1+\left( \frac{cx+dy}{ax+by}\right)^2}\cdot\frac{(bc-ad)y}{(ax+by)^2}$$
Hence we must have 
$$\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{f_1 df_2 - f_2 df_1}{f_1^2 + f_2^2} = \left[ \arctan \left( \frac{cx-d}{ax-b}\right) \right]_{x=-1}^1=\arctan \left( \frac{c-d}{a-b}\right) - \arctan \left( \frac{-c-d}{-a-b}\right)$$
Actually, it looks like I got the signs reversed earlier, where I claimed that
$$\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{f_1 df_2 - f_2 df_1}{f_1^2 + f_2^2} = - \arctan \left( \frac{c-d}{a-b} \right) + \arctan \left( \frac{-c-d}{-a-b} \right)$$
 but if I change the signs then all terms cancel and I get $0$, which is still not the right answer. I'm very confused now!

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Difficult to say since you do not show what you are doing.

Comment: @Did You're right, that was stupid of me. I've edited everything in now.

Comment: How did you compute, say, the integral on $\gamma_1$?

Comment: @Did I've edited that in as well. Things got worse.

Comment: For linear vector field you can always find suitable change of coordinates, which make formulas of vector field much easier. So, find the coordinates where vector field has simplest form, find index in these coordinates and use (or prove) the statement that the value of the integral is invariant under suitable change of coordinates.